# 80s film where a group of kids are stuck in a orbiting space shuttle and receive advice from a female astronaut

Tags: story-identification

I am looking for this movie that I saw as a kid on the early 90s (though I am fairly sure it was a film from the 80s). All I remember was that this group of young kids somehow got stuck on a space shuttle that was shot into orbit and then they must perform repairs and follow the advice of a female astronaut in order to safely make reentry.

Comment: Because the space shuttle came down eventually...

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Seems virtually certain this is [*SpaceCamp*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091993/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) (1986).

I haven't actually seen the movie, but the basic plot is that a bunch of kids at the NASA sponsored SpaceCamp are given the chance to tour a Space Shuttle on the actual launch pad -- I know of no sensible reason this would have been allowed with the External Tank fueled (and during the relatively short time it could be kept so before boiloff of the propellants was a major issue) -- but somehow, while they were aboard, the Shuttle got launched and automatic systems put it into an orbit (ignore the need for OMS maneuvers to ensure the ET is burned up in atmosphere and the orbiter kept in orbit).

So now, we have half a dozen teenagers and their mid-20s counselor in orbit, none of them qualified pilots, never mind trained astronauts.

This is why I haven't watched the movie, but the overall plot is that they do, in fact, manage to reenter and land the Orbiter safely.

Comment: Just occurred to the terrible timing this movie had -- releasing mere months after the loss of *Challenger* and her crew.

Comment: That's the one. I never realised as a kid the terrible timing this movie had. I believe I mush have watched it around 1992 or 1993.

Comment: If you think _that’s_ bad, try Apollo 13! A spaceship on the way to the moon in the 1970s has a problem, and the screenwriters would have us believe the astronauts can somehow build carbon dioxide scrubbers using spare parts and some plastic bags!

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Well, that's what happens when you put Forrest Gump in command of your moon shot.

Comment: It's not logical, but they at least try to address some of it. The camp counsellor is an astronaut, waiting for her turn to pilot a mission - she handles the OMS burns and orbital insertion.

Comment: OVERTEMP ON BOOSTER B

Comment: @Michael But somehow it's the kid who failed the least on the attitude adjustment test who has the controls when the re-enter the atmosphere. It's not the worst movie of the 80s by far, but it's far-fetched in several ways.

Comment: Oh yeah. As much fantasy as it is SF in that regard. But it's an important lesson in team work? Hard work? Accepting people's differences? Hmm, actually not so sure now I think about it...

Comment: @Michael. I think the lesson and meta-lesson here is that if you do a job badly enough, they won't ask you to do it again :)

Comment: Max... in... spaaaaaaaace.....

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: If you want bad timing for Apollo 13, check out [Marooned](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0064639).  As Commander Jim and his two crewmen adjust to weightlessness, an explosion occurs, taking out the spacecraft's main engine.  After realizing that they have not been hit my a meteor, the astronauts shut down fuel cells 2 and 3.  The director at mission control declares that he will use every resource to get the crew home.  A plan is devised to use another engine to send the astronauts back to Earth.  Four months before the real thing.

Comment: Poorly timed movie?  How about *A.I.*?  Climactic scene depicts ruined future New York City, complete with World Trade Center still mostly intact.  Released a few months before 9/11.

Comment: I think some robot gets them launched, if I recall correctly

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - *The China Syndrome* came out 12 days before Three Mile Island meltdown.

Comment: I heard that NASA changed launch pad procedures as a direct result of this incident

Comment: @ZeissIkon gave me a great laugh here  :)

Comment: "This is why I haven't watched the movie"  It had Kate Capshaw, Kelly Preston, AND Lea Thompson.  There was a 0% chance 13-year-old me wasn't watching it

Comment: @Hannover and the problem depicted in *China Syndrome* was eeriely similar: faulty indicator making them think the core was well covered, when it was not.

Comment: @DSheldon That's not the plot of 'Marooned' at all. The crew are at the end of a five-month Skylab-type mission but as they prepare to come home the Service Module engine simply fails to fire. No explosion, no shutting down their fuel cells. And their oxygen will last just 43 hours, meaning any rescue attempt has to be put together fast. In the end the Russians help out - this film has been credited with helping to inspire the real-life Apollo-Soyuz Test Project.